# Why do links to PDF documents now require https to work on Android phones?

Tags: android, pdf, https

We have a file server on which we place PDF documents and then embed links to them in a smart device app. Up until recently, using links to the PDF documents starting with http:// worked fine for Android and iPhone users. All could load the PDF file just fine. Then a few months back (approximately) Android phone users started reporting they would get an error when trying to load any PDF. Yet iPhone users had no issues loading the same PDF document. It was verified that these PDF documents (several) were not corrupted and opened fine when placed on another file server.

I have an iPhone so I can't give you the exact error msg received by Android users but to reproduce it, it was along the lines of... click the link to the PDF, a button appears showing View PDF, click that button and several apps appear to choose the app to open the PDF with, click one (like Adobe Reader, or Google Drive) and an error appears stating the file could not be opened and may be corrupted of the wrong syntax.

Tonight I found the solution.

The url to the PDF on all these documents on our server had been like http://...
but when I changed it to https://... it works fine.

I can't find ANYWHERE any mention of a change by Google that this is now a requirement.

**My question...**
Can someone explain and/or point me to a reference that explains why https must be used in embedded links to PDF documents? It seems like a pretty big deal to make this a requirement and not tell anyone. My searching the internet has so far not turned up anything.

Comment: usesClearTextTraffic="true"

Comment: This isn't new. HTTP traffic is disabled by default in apps for years now. You can re enable it as mentioned by @blackapps.

Comment: The http: version of the link worked fine up until a month or so ago. Something is new.